# Intellij IDEA: highlighting loop break points

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, intellij-14

In Eclipse, there's a possibility to highlight loop break points: I can place the cursor onto the `break;`, and the very loop it breaks out from will be highlighted:

[image]

Still, this functionality seems to be missing from IDEA:

[image]

Is there any hidden preference or a 3rd party plug-in which enables the same for IDEA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature has been introduced in [IntelliJ 2018.2](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/06/intellij-idea-2018-2-goes-beta/):

> When you place a caret at the break or continue keyword, IntelliJ IDEA highlights the for or while keyword of the corresponding loop.
>
> [image]
> <sub>(source: [cloudfront.net](https://d3nmt5vlzunoa1.cloudfront.net/idea/files/2018/06/image22.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The closest that I can get to what you're describing is to using the "Find Declaration" shortcut (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>), which requires that you highlight the `break` instead of the loop.

If you're in a method that returns `void`, it will take you to the outermost bracket that will be broken out of.  In certain cases in methods that return it will point to the return statement instead, which makes the feature not entirely reliable.

While this will properly show you which loop it breaks out of, to my knowledge there is nothing in vanilla IntelliJ that does what you describe out-of-the-box.

Comment: Which version of IDEA are you running? In IDEA 14.1, *Navigate* -> *Declaration* (with `break` selected) just points me to the method's return point (not related to the `break`'s enclosing loop).

Comment: I'm on IDEA 14.1.1.  In a `void` method I observe the above; in a non-void method I observe what you're seeing.  I'll add that info to the answer.

Comment: This is no longer the case with IDEA **2016.3** (Navigate -> Declaration brings me to an arbitrary line *after* -- and outside -- the loop).

Answer (score 1):

Try placing cursor at `break`, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>